# Exception thrown: Access violation reading location in VS 2012. (In VS2010 not)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, visual-studio-2012

I wrote a simple program to test cascade classifiers.
In the following code snippet I get an access violation exteption at the "push_back" command in VS2012:

```
vector<CascadeClassifier> objectCascadeVec;
CascadeClassifier classTemp;
if(!classTemp.load("atestxmlfile.xml"))
{
    cout << "Error while loading the xml file\n";
    exit(0);
}
objectCascadeVec.push_back(classTemp);
```

In VS2010 this code did not throw excteption, it has worked. Why is it not working in VS2012?

Comment: afaik, you can't copy a CascadeClassifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of this problem was, that I used VS2010 before VS2012. When I installed VS2012, I havn't modified the path of the OpenCV dll files. I had to modifie the environment variable of the OpenCV files to vc11 folder, because these dll files are proper to the compiler of VS2012.